# which way should i define Resource Dictionaries to keep my code clean?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

I am new to WPF. My requirement is to implement the styling in a clean way. Styling includes fonts, colors, layouts, size,. etc.

[image: Style]

Sample implementation with style is shown above. Requirement is in a window if its a form which receives input from user, common style needs to there like label has to right aligned, textbox has to be left aligned and some width and some properties and foreground property too.

**My implementation**

I made a separate assembly (because not only for this purpose it includes other user controls, styles, resources) which has a Layout.Xaml resource dictionary and in it all styles are defined.

Then a dependency property is created and through that the dictionary is linked as shown below.

```
<Window xmlns:MvvmLibsTests="clr-namespace:CreativeEye.TestConsole.MvvmLibsTests"  
        x:Class="CreativeEye.TestConsole.MvvmLibsTests.StyleTestView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SyleTestView" Height="408" Width="706"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"        
        xmlns:Styles="clr-namespace:CreativeEye.MvvmLibs.Behaviours;assembly=CreativeEye.MvvmLibs">

<!--<Grid>-->
<Grid Styles:SetLayout.Resources="{StaticResource FormLayoutStyle}">
</Grid>
</Window>
```

In that **FormLayoutStyle** has value

```
 <s:String x:Key="FormLayoutStyle">pack://application:,,,/CreativeEye.MvvmLibs;component/Resources/Layout.xaml</s:String>
```

in App.Xaml of the application.

The code for dependency property is

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourcesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Resources",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(SetLayout),
            new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(CallBack)));

    private static void CallBack(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var layoutGridStylePath = e.NewValue;

        if (layoutGridStylePath == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var uri = new Uri((string)layoutGridStylePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        var grid = obj as FrameworkElement;

        if (grid == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        grid.Resources.Source = uri;
    }
```

And i achieved the result.

> But i wanted to know is it a good way ?

and also i read some thing about memory leaks.
Reference links [link 1](http://discoveringdotnet.alexeyev.org/2011/11/resourcedictionary-and-memory-leaks.html), [link 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b97a5f83-5394-430e-9a78-9d3a957e3537/dynamicresourcestaticresource-cause-memory-leaks?forum=wpf).

I was more confused. I couldn't understand properly.

> Can anyone please say in my implementation such memory leak problem will be der ?

Comment: great idea, good job

Answer (score 1):

Generally i use resources this way, but binding to c# code is also not at all a bad approach.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDemo.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary 
                  Source="Resources/MyResourceDictionary.xaml">
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary 
                  Source="Resources/OthersStyle.xaml">
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="/Images/logo.jpg"></Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```